# How do I use both a laptop and a desktop under one license?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-provisioning

I have been developing on my Mac Mini.  I have just paid to join the iOS Developer Program, and I am about to set up a provisioning profile.

Tomorrow I am going to do some significant travelling on business.  The purpose of travel is to show the project running on a couple phones.  I will only have my MacBook with me.

Is it possible for me to set up the laptop and the desktop to provision the same phones?

Maybe the simpler way to put it is: I have to be able to use the laptop to get the app on the phones, because I have to be able to modify and re-deploy the code while away from home.  But when I'm home I would much rather use the Mini for day-to-day development.

Is it possible for me to have a setup where both the MacBook and the Mini can work on the same code, and they both can provision the same phones?

And if it is possible, links to any instructions on how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question can be seen in the [WWDC 2011 Video: Session 317 - Device Management and App Submission with Xcode 4](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/). Go to about 35 minutes in (the section entitled "Tips and Tricks").

In short, you need to export the developer profile on your home computer, and import it onto your laptop. Go to the organiser, select the "Devices" tab, and click on "Developer Profile" in the navigation pane. Click on "Export" at the bottom, name the profile and give it a password. Then place the file on your laptop, go to the Xcode organiser on your laptop and select "Import" under the developer profile section. Once you've entered the password and clicked "Open", you're done and ready to codesign, build and run on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org) or [git](http://git-scm.com/) for keeping dynamic copies of code on a server.

Provisioning is done through the developer portal and can be accessed from both machines.